# What are my options for implementing AES256 encryption on my embedded device running Linux 2.4.x without updating the OS?

Tags: python, encryption, openssl, embedded, aes

The embedded device I use has no apt, dpkg etc. It still runs on linux 2.4.x. I need the OpenSSL extention for the terminal so that i can crypt files via AES256.
Sadly there is no possibility to update the linux version or install it remotly on every device manualy as my softwarechanges need to be shipped to thoudsands of devices.

I tried to somehow create a own python function thats Rijndael like. But it´s pretty tough without the allowance to use external libraries.
I´d like to try to somehow use the OpenSSL sourcecode and implement it into our Projectfolder and rewrite the makefile, so it gets thrown in the right directories. Is there some Kind of possibility to do this?

Is there an other way to implement AES256 into my python code?

Comment: There are public domain C implementations on the Internet, I've used one recently. You could probably easily make a C tool that you can call from your python program.

Comment: This was the very first result when I entered `pure python aes implementation` into my search engine: https://github.com/boppreh/aes . I have no idea if it's useful but you can certainly give it a try.